# VBA with multiple discounts & Problem of next without for & insert value in respective cell

Tags: excel, vba

The problem here is we've got a promotion for fruits, herbs and vegetables. A vba code is needed under several discounts rules.

- Cauliflower, Guava and mango are on sale, with 30% off discount, will not be affected by the order quantity.

Fruits category:

- No discount for order quantity less than 5 cases.
- 10% discount if order quantity from 5 to 15 cases.
- 20% discount for more than 15 cases.

Herbs category:

- No discount for order quantity less than 10 cases.
- 5% discount if order quantity from 10 to 15 cases.
- 10% discount for more than 15 cases.

Vegetables category:

- Kale: 12% discount for 20 cases or more
- Others:  12% discount for 5 cases or more

However, I am facing the issue of "next without for"......and I could not see where is the lack...and secondly may I know how to insert the respective discount in column D (under percentage). Any suggestion and help are more than appreciated. Thx !!

```
Sub Task3()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Integer
    Dim thisCategory As String, thisProduct As String
    Dim thisQty As Integer
    Dim Sale As Boolean
    Dim discount As Single

    With Sheets("sheet1")
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("D1").Value = "Discount"

    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        thisCategory = Cells(i, 1).Value
        thisProduct = Cells(i, 2).Value
        thisQty = Cells(i, 3).Value

        Select Case thisProduct
            Case "Cauliflower"
                Sale = thisProduct
            Case "Guava"
                Sale = thisProduct
            Case "Mango"
                Sale = thisProduct
        End Select

        If Sale Then
            discount = 0.3
        Else
            If thisCategory = "Fruits" Then
                Select Case thisQty
                    Case Is < 5
                        discount = 0
                    Case 5 To 15
                        discount = 0.1
                    Case Is > 15
                        discount = 0.2
                End Select

            ElseIf thisCategory = "Herbs" Then
                Select Case thisQty
                    Case Is < 10
                        discount = 0
                    Case 10 To 15
                        discount = 0.05
                    Case Is > 15
                        discount = 0.1
                End Select

            ElseIf thisCategory = "Vegetables" Then
                    If thisProduct = "Kale" And thisQty >= 20 Then
                        discount = 0.12
                    ElseIf thisProduct <> "Kale" And thisQty >= 5 Then
                        discount = 0.12
                    End If
        End If
        ' insert discount in column D


         If discount = 0.3 Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Interior.Color = vbYellow
         End If
    Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Next Without For` -> You're missing an `End If`. Better [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) should help spot it.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I pasted the code there and press indent! but seems nth has changed...

Comment: You need an `End If` before `Next i`

Comment: ohh it's working now I guess ! Thanks brother !!

Comment: The last thing is to add the respective discount on column D in percentage form...and I have no idea on how to get it...

Comment: Format the cell as *Percentage*. That will divide the value by 100 and add a percentage sign.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot variatus! its just that I cannot insert the respective discount value into the D column cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed your code, added some comments and the two lines need to set the discount. I hope it works for you.

```
Sub Task3()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Integer
    Dim thisCategory As String, thisProduct As String
    Dim thisQty As Integer
    Dim Sale As Boolean
    Dim discount As Single

    With Sheets("sheet1")
        ' use a leading period to identify each item that
        ' VBA should find in Sheets("sheet1") specified with "With"
        ' I marked every added period with *
        FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     ' **

        .Range("D1").Value = "Discount"                     ' *

        For i = 2 To FinalRow
            thisCategory = .Cells(i, 1).Value               ' *
            thisProduct = .Cells(i, 2).Value                ' *
            thisQty = .Cells(i, 3).Value                    ' *

            Select Case thisProduct
                Case "Cauliflower"
                    Sale = thisProduct
                Case "Guava"
                    Sale = thisProduct
                Case "Mango"
                    Sale = thisProduct
            End Select

            If Sale Then
                discount = 0.3
            Else
                If thisCategory = "Fruits" Then
                    Select Case thisQty
                        Case Is < 5
                            discount = 0
                        Case 5 To 15
                            discount = 0.1
                        Case Is > 15
                            discount = 0.2
                    End Select

                ElseIf thisCategory = "Herbs" Then
                    Select Case thisQty
                        Case Is < 10
                            discount = 0
                        Case 10 To 15
                            discount = 0.05
                        Case Is > 15
                            discount = 0.1
                    End Select

                ElseIf thisCategory = "Vegetables" Then
                        If thisProduct = "Kale" And thisQty >= 20 Then
                            discount = 0.12
                        ElseIf thisProduct <> "Kale" And thisQty >= 5 Then
                            discount = 0.12
                        End If
            End If
            ' insert discount in column D


            With .Cells(i, 4)
                .Value = discount
                .NumberFormat = "0%"
                If discount = 0.3 Then
                    .Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 4).Interior.Color = vbYellow   '*
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow !!! You are a lifesaver !! Thank you from the bottom of my heart!!  Everything goes well but just one small problem... the discounts of the three on sale products (Cauliflower, guava and mango) are not 30%